# What is a "posterior median"?

Tags: bayesian, terminology, posterior

I know what the term "posterior distribution" means (namely the conditional probability distribution of some parameter with respect to some observed data), but I'm reading an author that uses the qualifier "posterior" *all over the place*, mostly in contexts that I can't make any sense of.

For example, "posterior median".  What could this possibly be?

Edit: based on the comments/answers I've received it looks like my question should have been closer to "what is the median of a *distribution* (as opposed to a sample)?"

More generally, is "posterior" just shorthand for "conditional on some observed values"?

Comment: "The median of the posterior distribution"; distributions have medians.

Answer (score 10):

Well, you have posterior means, posterior modes, posterior standard deviations... any functional relationship calculated in a probability density can be calculated in a posterior density.